# Change the string output to int to obtain the maximum number?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I am quite new to python so still getting to grips with the language.

I have the following function which takes a string and apply it to an algorithm which tells us if it aligns to models 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

Currently this piece of code:

```
def apply_text(text):
    test_str = [text]
    test_new = tfidf_m.transform(test_str)
    prediction = 0
    for m in range(0,5):
        percentage = '{P:.1%}'.format(M=cat[m], P=lr_m[m].predict_proba(test_new)[0][1])
        print(percentage)
```

And running the following function: `apply_text('Terrible idea.')`

Gives the following output:

```
71.4%
33.1%
2.9%
1.6%
4.9%
```

With Model 1 = 71.4%, Model 2 = 33.1%, ... Model 5 = 4.9%.

I want to only output the Model number where there is the highest percentage. So in the above example, the answer would be `1` as this has 71.4%. 
As the output is a string type I am finding it difficult to find ways of converting this to an `int` and then comparing each value (probably in a loop of some sort) to obtain the maximum value

Comment: Try storing all the percentage values in a dictionary with model no. as key and percentage as value:
dictionary = {'model_1': pct_value_1, 'model_2': pct_value_2} and so on.

Then sort the data in descending order and grab the first key: value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting values in a list then you can utilize list methods:

```py
percentage = []
for m in range(0, 5):
    percentage.append('{P:.1%}'.format(M=cat[m], P=lr_m[m].predict_proba(test_new)[0][1]))

print(*percentage, sep='\n')
print('Max on model', percentage.index(max(percentage)))
```

Or using a dictionary:

```py
percentage = {}
for m in range(0, 5):
    percentage['Model ' + str(m)] = '{P:.1%}'.format(M=cat[m], P=lr_m[m].predict_proba(test_new)[0][1])

print(*percentage, sep='\n')
print('Max on', max(percentage.keys(), key=(lambda key: percentage[key])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to save the percentages along with the model number, sort it and then return the highest.

This can be done by something like this:

```
def apply_text(text):
    test_str = [text]
    test_new = tfidf_m.transform(test_str)
    prediction = 0
    percentage_list = []
    for m in range(0,5):
        percentage = '{P:.1}'.format(M=cat[m], P=lr_m[m].predict_proba(test_new)[0][1])
        percentage_list.append([m+1, float(percentage)])

    percentage_list.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda a: a[1])
    return percentage_list[0][0]
```

Things to note:

1. Sorting in reverse order as default is ascending. You could skip reversing and access the last element of `precentage_list` by accessing -1 element
2. The key function is used as we need to sort using the percentage